# Disable excel save changes prompt

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I have tried all the ways I normally do this and what I can find searching.  `oxl.DisplayAlerts = False` is not working.  I still get asked if I want to save changes.

I am essentially trying to use the excel sheet as a template.  The full script exports to pdf, but this is enough to re-create the problem.  BTW I tried saving it as a xltx file (template) and still get the save promt.

```
Dim oxl As New Excel.Application
Dim apppath2 As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString
Dim mywb As Excel.Workbook = oxl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=apppath2 & "\fuse template.xlsx", [ReadOnly]:=True)
oxl.Visible = False

Dim mysheet As Excel.Worksheet = mywb.Sheets(1)
mysheet.Cells(10, 5) = l_region.Text
mysheet.Cells(11, 5) = comb_emc_name.Text

oxl.DisplayAlerts = False
mywb.Close(False)
mysheet = Nothing
mywb = Nothing
oxl = Nothing
GC.Collect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing `mywb.Saved = True`. I have never had to do that before.